# Is it possible to calculate differences in values between rows in a column using MySQL without a CTE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

Table 1:

| Id_Number | Name | Arrival Date and Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ted | 10/27/20, 4:00 PM |
| 2 | Joe | 10/27/20, 4:00 PM |
| 3 | Ted | 10/27/20, 5:30 PM |
| 4 | Joe | 10/27/20, 5:10 PM |
| 5 | Joe | 10/27/20, 5:30 PM |

Desired Result:

| Id_Number | Name | Travel Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ted | null |
| 2 | Joe | null |
| 3 | Ted | 90 min |
| 4 | Joe | 70 min |
| 5 | Joe | 20 min |

I'd like to calculate the travel time difference between rows per journey. If there was no prior journey for a Name, then the Travel Time should be null.

Is this possible without a CTE?

Edit: I should have specified that I also do *not* have access to Lead(), Lag(), Partition, or Over.

Comment: CTE not needed for this task. At all. Use `LAG()` function.

Comment: PS. CTE can be converted to subquery almost everywhere (maybe in a lot of copies).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your opposition to CTE?

Comment: While I'm confident I could solve this with a CTE and the Lead, Lag functions-- the platform I use for work does not give me access to these operators. It very much hinders my ability.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT Id_Number, 
       Name, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(`Arrival Date and Time`) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY `Arrival Date and Time`), `Arrival Date and Time`) `Travel Time`
FROM source_table
ORDER BY Id_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function lag as follows:

```
Select t.*,
       Case when lgdt <> date_col 
            then timestampdiff(minute, date_col, lgdt)
       End as diff
From
(Select t.*,
       Lag(date_col) over (order by date) as lgdt
  From t) t
```

Comment: No need for the subquery, as `LAG` can appear in the outer select directly.

Comment: Added subquery to check if lag and current row date are same then null need to be displayed.

Comment: No need for that, as the default return value for the single argument version of `LAG` (e.g. when there is no lag value) is `NULL`.

Comment: You misunderstood. Check the second row in expected output.